# Checking if an object is null or undefined in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have 2 object, one takes person details and other one takes address details via form. And each object has 3 fields. Now, before I send this to my parent, I need an check if condition these 2 objects are not undefined or null

I have tried these conditions and all fail:

=> `!(this.person)&&!(this.address)`

=> `this.person !=(null || undefined)`

I know that I can also compare each property of the object to null or undefined but can't write 6 conditions, because it breaches coding standards.

So guys please help me with this

Comment: !(this.person || this.address)

Answer (score 6):

Its not really and Angular things its more to do with Javascript. A double equal to null will return true if its null or undefined.

```
if (someValue == null) {
 // Do something if null or undefined
}
```

This table should help.

[image]

Comment: interesting table

Answer (score 5):

Use a function

```
function areNullOrUndefined(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     var itm = arr[i];
     if (itm === null || itm === undefined) {
       return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var bool = areNullOrUndefined([this.person, this.address]);
```

You could work around coding standards this way...

Or with a oneliner:

```
var bool = [this.person, this.address].some(itm => itm === null || itm === undefined);
```